# Check & remove special characters in a field?

Tags: custom-field, text, customization, characters

I would like to check whether a field has special characters, remove those characters and output (save) the value to another field.

I am creating a user search function that search various fields, but those fields might (or might not) have special characters in them that will return unexpected results, or no results at all. I need to be able to remove any special characters and save/output the clean value to another field, which I will then include in my search function.

**Example:**

**Original value:**

G-P's Bargain Shop

**After removing special characters:**

GPs Bargin Shop

Then **save new value** (GPs Bargain Shop) to **another field**

Can someone tell me how to achieve this? Or of a better solution for what Im trying to accomplish. Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex to only allow alphanumeric characters.

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);
```

Comment: thanks. This worked for me, but now Im noticing a problem with the ampersand character (&). I was able to set up a replacement system that will replace "&" with the word "and." The new value saves to database correctly, but when I search the new value Im not able to get and results with my custom query. The ampersand character translate to &amp; in html and I think this has something to do with my issue.